# Adding contacts using swift file

Tags: swift, contacts

I am trying to write a swift file that will create new contacts in my address book

```
import Contacts

let newContact = CNMutableContact()
newContact.givenName = "First"
newContact.familyName = "Last"

let number = CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: "(555) 555-5555")

newContact.phoneNumbers = [CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile, value: number)]


let store = CNContactStore()
let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
saveRequest.addContact(newContact, toContainerWithIdentifier:nil)
try store.executeSaveRequest(saveRequest)
```

When I run the file in terminal, it gives a very long error message, most of which is code that I don't understand. However, the first line says

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "fullNumber"; desired type = NSString; given type = CNPhoneNumber; value = .'

If I pass CNLabeledValue a String instead of a CNPhoneNumber like so

```
let number: NSString = "(555) 555-5555"

newContact.phoneNumbers = [CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile, value: number)]
```

it says this

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CNPropertyInvalidTypeException', reason: 'Labeled value !$_, value=(555) 555-5555> value (555) 555-5555 has incorrect type __NSCFString. It should be CNPhoneNumber.'

It's also worth noting that commenting out the final line

```
try store.executeSaveRequest(saveRequest)
```

Gets rid of the error, but of course does not add anything to my address book.

Needless to say, I am extremely confused

Comment: what version of iOS you run against?
I have no problems in running your code (translated to ObjectiveC) on iOS9.1

Comment: I suspect this is an OS X question. Ben, can you confirm?